# Is it possible to load 2 file explorer windows in 1 form?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

I would like to have a form that has 2 windows file explorer(explorer.exe) views.

I know I could code a file browser in a few days, but I much rather just use instances of explorer.  I dont need to re-invent the wheel, just two windows connected by a form.

Is this possible in C#?

Comment: If you really could code a file browser in a few days why are you posting here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/ExplorerTree.aspx) controller and then just too 2 of them in the same window

Answer (score 0):

There is no means by which to "host" an explorer window, as you want to do. The only way to come close is to use an `OpenFileDialog`, but that is obviously unsuited to what you're going for. There is no API around the explorer window; no matter what approach you take, you're going to have to use an actual control. There are plenty available online, such as the one linked to by Baget, but nothing built into .NET.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use embeddable controls like [Shell MegaPack](http://www.ssware.com/megapack.htm) for this.